# How to set a date and store as a string and converts to a date datatype in Java?

Tags: java

I need help in converting a string to a date datatype in Java. I will have to receive a String key in by user and converts to the date datatype.

That means I'm setting my own date and converting to a date datatype.

Comment: Heh i have searched in google but i only get the codes which the output is the current time.. So i really have no idea how to do :X

Comment: take a look at this. didnt even take me a minute. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, define a `SimpleDateFormat` format and create a date `String` object that follows the format you predefined. Use `SimpleDateFormat.parse(String)` to convert a `String` to `java.util.Date` object.

More details, please take a look at [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html).

For complete date and time patterns, please refer to this [java.text.SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) JavaDoc.

Comment: import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
public class bla {
  public static void main(String[] a) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
 
    Date date = dateFormat.parse(text);
    
    }
}

Comment: Correct. As long as the String 'text' object, as in 'yyyy-MM-dd' format, you would be able to convert it into a Date object.